# How to make the width of all the boxes the same

Tags: dm-script

Hi, all:
I'd like to make the UI more organized. One problem is that we can't define the box width. One possible solution is to add an empty label with fixed width to define the width of box. But it looks a little strange (an empty line). Is there any better method?

[image]

Regards

ChenZX

Comment: Is the posted image your aimed-for-dialog or what you currently have? It would be good to see a (mockup) of the dialog you want, and the one you currently have.  The two answers below likely need to be "combined" to give you the right design, and it will need a bit of fiddling around. But "internal padding" plus "external padding" of individual items gives you a lot of flexibility. the "fill" parameter auto-resizes elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it differently than Kevivi in his post. Basing my script on his:

Kevivi's script gives:

[image]

Mine gives:

[image]

Setting the "internal padding" property of the group box allows specification of the borders relative to the content box:

[image]

```c
class UIExample : UIFrame {
    number true, false;     // boolean

    void DoEnableAction( object self ) OkDialog( "Enable button pushed" );
    
    void DoDisableAction( object self ) OkDialog( "Disable button pushed" );

    void ConstructAndDisplayUI( object self ) {
        TagGroup tgDialog = DLGCreateDialog( "UIFrame Example");
        //  create push buttons
        TagGroup tgButton1 = DLGCreatePushButton( "Enable", "DoEnableAction" );
        TagGroup tgButton2 = DLGCreatePushButton( "Disable", "DoDisableAction" );
        
        TagGroup tgGroup = DLGGroupItems( tgButton1, tgButton2 );
        tgGroup.DLGTableLayout(2,1, false);
               
        // create a box and add button group as element
        TagGroup tgBox = DLGCreateBox( "settings" )//.DLGAnchor("North")//.DLGFill("XY");
        tgBox.DLGAddElement( tgGroup );
        
        // Specify the "internal" rect of the box. (0,0,0,0) would be exactly matching the content
        // The parameters are T, L, B, R and specifying offset for each
        tgBox.DLGInternalPadding(-20,-10,10,10)
        
        // add box as UI element
        tgDialog.DLGAddElement( tgBox );
        self.init(tgDialog);
        self.Display( "UIFrame example" );
    };

    UIExample( object self ) {      // object constructor
        // assign boolean
        true = 1;
        false = 0;
        // object construction verbage;
        result( "object \"UIExample\" (" + self.ScriptObjectGetID() + ") constructed\n" );
    };
    
    ~UIExample( object self ) {     // object destructor
        // object destruction verbage;
        result( "object \"UIExample\" (" + self.ScriptObjectGetID() + ") destructed\n\n" );
    };

};

alloc( UIExample ).ConstructAndDisplayUI();
```

Comment: Please note that the initial answer was posted by KEVIVI, not Mike.

Comment: Thanks for your quick action. There is still one reference to Mike in your first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy (or direct) way to control the box width, it will depend on the size of containing elements. The example codes below show how I will handle this situation - using the "DLGInternalPadding()" to adjust the push button size.

```
class UIExample : UIFrame {
    number true, false;     // boolean

    void DoEnableAction( object self ) OkDialog( "Enable button pushed" );
    
    void DoDisableAction( object self ) OkDialog( "Disable button pushed" );

    void ConstructAndDisplayUI( object self ) {
        TagGroup tgDialog = DLGCreateDialog( "UIFrame Example");
        //  create push buttons
        number padding_x =30, padding_y =5;
        TagGroup tgButton1 = DLGCreatePushButton( "Enable", "DoEnableAction" );
            tgButton1.DLGInternalPadding(padding_x, padding_y).DLGFill("XY");
        TagGroup tgButton2 = DLGCreatePushButton( "Disable", "DoDisableAction" );
            tgButton2.DLGInternalPadding(padding_x, padding_y).DLGFill("XY");
        // group push buttons
        TagGroup tgGroup = DLGGroupItems( tgButton1, tgButton2 );
            tgGroup.DLGTableLayout(2,1, true);
        // create a box and add button group as element
        TagGroup tgBox = DLGCreateBox( "settings" ).DLGFill("XY");
            tgBox.DLGAddElement( tgGroup );
        
        // add box as UI element
        tgDialog.DLGAddElement( tgBox );
        self.init(tgDialog);
        self.Display( "UIFrame example" );
    };

    UIExample( object self ) {      // object constructor
        // assign boolean
        true = 1;
        false = 0;
        // object construction verbage;
        result( "object \"UIExample\" (" + self.ScriptObjectGetID() + ") constructed\n" );
    };
    
    ~UIExample( object self ) {     // object destructor
        // object destruction verbage;
        result( "object \"UIExample\" (" + self.ScriptObjectGetID() + ") destructed\n\n" );
    };

};

alloc( UIExample ).ConstructAndDisplayUI();
```